# Transform wkb to gml geometry using FME

Tags: sql-server, fme-form, gml, well-known-text, well-known-binary

Maybe (and probably) this is stupid question, but I am totaly new to FME and geometry conversion.

I need to transform WKB field from SQLServer to GML geometry using FME software.

How can I do this?

Comment: is WKB as WKB in SQL or as geometry, if geometry just add sql spatial reader and it just works. Or if it is as WKB use STGeomFromWKB (assuming 2008 r2+ version of ms sql) to convert it to geometry and use normal sql spatial reader

Comment: @simplexio varbinary SQLServer field needs to be transformed to gml geometry. I'll try as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS SQL server Create new table or add new column. Use STGeomFromWKB to convert WKB to Geometry , then in FME do following.

Add "MS SQL spatial reader" , point it to correct table ( You can do this with SQLExecute too , that eliminates need for table containing geometry type and you can just use something like `SELECT STGeomFRomWKB(wkb) as geom , id from xxx ...` ) and continue to use FME

Comment: When fne read new table, the geometry field is gone. It doesnt see it.

Comment: Done, it was my mistake. It doesnt write it in gml I want, but it works somehow. Thanks! P.S. I wanna vote up, but Im short with reps :-/

Comment: now you need to select GML writer in FME and write data to there.

Comment: I know that part, but my problem was that I didnt know that he transforms GEOMETRY field autimaticaly. Tnx